# How to change permissions in file system within aws lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am getting an permission error , executing a lamba function. error is => [Error 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user'

I'm using some python packages in my aws lamba , and i supposed one of those libraries , tries to access/read/write into aws lambda file system.

is it possible to change file/folder permission within aws lambda ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U cannot change local file system beside the lambda dedicated space

*Each execution environment provides between 512 MB and 10,240 MB, in 1-MB 
increments, of disk space in the /tmp directory. The directory content 
 remains when the execution environment is frozen, providing a transient cache  
 that can be used for multiple invocations. You can add extra code to check 
 if the cache has the data that you stored. For more information on 
 deployment size limits, see Lambda quotas.*

as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50947102/7837926)
see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html)